# jQuery effects doesn't work when I refresh the page next time

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I use jQuery and Ajax. when I refresh the page, jQuery UI effects get applied to Ajax response.

But when I send another post back, the jQuery UI effects don't apply to the new response.

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sendemp").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var submit_val = $("#searchbox").val();
            //alert('submitval is ' + submit_val);


            $.ajax( {
                type : "POST",
                //dataType :"jason",
                url : "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data : {
                    action : 'employee_pimary_details',
                    user_name : submit_val
                },
                success : function(data) {
                //      alert('hhh');
                    $('#accordion21').html(data);
                    // $( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
                    // source: data
                    // });
                }
            });
        });
   });
```

I use jQuery accordion box. The response I get from  `$('#accordion21').html(data);` will be applied jQuery UI Accordion.

In my php code, I have the following

```
$jason .=  '<h3 style="font-size:15px;">';
    foreach($employee as $key=> $value){
        $jason .= '<table><tbody>';
        $jason .= '<tr><td style="width:400px;padding:5px;padding:10px;"></td><td style="width:300px;padding:5px;"><img style="width:132px; height:175px;" src="'.$image_folder.$value->prfil_img .'" /></td></tr>';
    //$retval .= '<a href="'. $store_url . 'product_info.php?products_id=' . $product_id . '"><img src="' . $image_folder . $product_image . '" /></a><br />';

        $jason .= '<tr><td style="width:30%;font-size:14px;paddig:10px;">'.'Name:'.'</td>'.'<td style="font-size:14px;paddig:5px;">'.$value->first_name.'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$value->last_name.'</td></tr>';
        $jason .= '<tr><td style="width:30%;font-size:14px;paddig:10px;">'.'Email:'.'</td>'.'<td style="font-size:14px;paddig:5px;">'.$value->email;'</td></tr>';
        $jason .= '<tr><td style="width:30%;font-size:14px;paddig:10px;">'.'Tel Ext:'.'</td>'.'<td style="font-size:14px;paddig:5px;">'.$value->extension;'</td></tr>';
        $jason .= '<tr><td style="width:30%;font-size:14px;paddig:10px;">'.'att:'.'</td>'.'<td style="font-size:14px;paddig:5px;">'.$value->att;'</td></tr>';
        $jason .= '</table></tbody>';
        // echo '</br>';echo '</br>';

   }
        $jason .= '</h3>';
```

jQuery UI will be applied to `<h3>`  and `<div>`

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: try to reproduce your issue with http://jsfiddle.net in your ajax request use "url: '/echo/html/'," to echo back the html data you post to it "data: {html: '<div />'},"

Comment: I don't see any jQuery UI effects here...

Comment: @Mehdiway I almost missed it too. `autocomplete`, it's uncommented

Comment: @Blade0rz you mean OP called `autocomplete` a jquery UI effect?

Comment: @roasted I guess so. This is Stack Overflow, half of the game is guessing what the person really means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I could solve this,

what I did was I changed the code on success

```
success : function(data) {
                //      alert('hhh');
                    $('#accordion3').accordion('destroy');
                    $('#accordion3').html(data);

                    $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#F8F8F8");
                    //$("#accordion3").accordion( "disable" );
                    $("#accordion3").accordion({ active: 0 });

                }
```

Out of `$(document).ready(function() {` I did the following change to code

```
 $(function() {
    $("#accordion3").accordion({ 
    // heightStyle: "fill",
    active: 0 });
  });
```

Reson to change the code as above is following link :)
[helped link](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

You want to initialise the `autocomplete` on page load, then on subsequent ajax requests you want to assign the `source` via the setter method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchbox").autocomplete({ source: [] });
    $("#sendemp").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var submit_val = $("#searchbox").val();
            //alert('submitval is ' + submit_val);


            $.ajax( {
                type : "POST",
                //dataType :"jason",
                url : "./wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data : {
                    action : 'employee_pimary_details',
                    user_name : submit_val
                },
                success : function(data) {
                //      alert('hhh');
                    $('#accordion21').html(data);
                     $( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete("option", "source", data);

                }
            });

        });
   });
```

But the jQuery UI Autocomplete actually provides code which does this automatically. Have a look at the documentation for the [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) property.